# Kernel panic not syncing attempted to kill init exit code 0x0000000b

Tags: linux-kernel, telnet, busybox

I am trying to debug telnetd on a Site Router by writing log to a log file. After adding some debug log to telnetd.c in busybox and load new firmware, i got the error like above. Can anyone here tell me how to fix it. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: For help, you would have to add the code up to the point that it prints `Open log file failed!!!`

Comment: thanks, i fixed it myself by changing boot slot in uboot